# dotnet core excluding tests project from building in launchSettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, rider

In JetBrains Rider, we can either manually create a profile to run a .NET Core Web app or use `launchSettings.json` file if it is included in the project. However, when I manually create a profile it does not build the tests projects but when I use the `launchSettings.json` it tries to build the tests projects (it's probably just running `dotnet build` without any filters). I am wondering what do I need to add to my `launchSettings.json` to exclude building the tests projects. Thank you

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:20169",
      "sslPort": 44329
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "Web": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Localhost"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The *launch settings* determine how the application is launched. It does not affect what projects are built. As such, there is no configuration within the launch settings that would possibly affect the build behavior. If Rider is looking on anything there, then its behavior is pretty non-standard there.

Comment: @poke there're two different _build modes_ in Rider/VS/probably other IDEs. When you're just _building_ the solution, it's one thing, and when your IDE _builds the project before run_ — that's another thing. IDE tries to build as little as possible when you're running your project (that means it shouldn't build irrelevant projects); that's what the author is asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's just a bug in Rider: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-23780

It should work as you describe (e.g. it should only build the projects required for the program to run if you click the "Run" button), but it doesn't work for Launch Settings yet.

The workaround is to either create a ".NET Project" run configuration instead of the "Launch Settings" one, or to manually exclude the projects from build.